# ¿Por qué esta api no funciona al publicar en Netlify mientras que al levantarla con la extensión Live Server de VSC si lo hace sin problemas?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Entiendo que toda api necesita de un sitio web "on air" y por ende, su consumo depende de un servidor propiamente dicho o una emulación del mismo. En este caso se utiliza el Visual Studio Code, y se "levanta" el proyecto a través de la extensión "Live Server" y esta es la que emula un servidor, y por ende, funciona tal api (a través de fetch). Cuando no es de esta forma, la manera como funciona Netlify y otros websites similares para subir proyectos (en este caso levanté el proyecto en Netlify arrastrando y soltando), difiere de ser un servidor propiamente con las características requeridas pues intuyo que tal como se publica un proyecto arrastrando y soltando, y no realizando un seteo y configuración de algunos elementos, hace que esto no suceda y funcione tipo "Live Server".

Así las cosas, estuve leyendo literatura relacionada tipo diferencias entre deployar, puesta en producción, publicar y compilar, pero lamentablemente no encuentro una respuesta significativa y simple de comprender de por qué la api funciona con Live Server de VSC apoyándome en fetch y deja de funcionar cuando la publico en Netlify.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("#btnClima")

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    let ciudad = document.querySelector('#ciudad').value
    ciudad = encodeURIComponent(ciudad)

    //let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + ciudad + "&appid=" + key
    let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${ciudad}&appid=${key}`

    console.log(url)

    if (ciudad != "") {
        fetch(url)
            .then((data) => {
                return data.json()
            })
            .then((clima) => {
                console.log(clima)
                let temp = clima.main.temp
                let tempC = temp - 273.15;
                let html = document.querySelector("#temperatura")
                html.innerHTML = tempC.toFixed(0)


                if (tempC < 10) {
                    html.className = "cold"
                } else {
                    html.className = "warm"
                }

            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Supermercado+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    
    <main class="container-fluid" id="fondo">
        <div class="divh1">
            <h1> Maquina del clima  ☁</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="label">
            <label for="ciudad">Nombre de la Ciudad</label>
        </div>

        <div class="imputuwu">
            <input type="text" id="ciudad" required>
        </div>

        <div class="boton">
            <button id="btnClima">Obtener Clima</button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tempi">
            <output>
                <p id="temperatura"></p>
            </output>
        </div>
        <div class="abajo">
            <div class="abajop">
                <h2>
                    Creadores:
                </h2>
            </div>
            
            <div class="abajop">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/antonellaotero8/" class="anto">Antonella Otero</a>
            </div>

            <div class="abajop">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/oteronahuel/" class="nahuel">Nahuel Otero</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: bueno.. aparte de ese detalle, que voy a borrar, te das cuenta que cuando publicas en netlify (por ejemplo) tu url cambia rotundamente??? y ademas el tipo de servidor es diferente, y espera servir diferentes cosas?

Comment: Igual, por favor, ahora pide que cambien eso.. ya quedo expuesta y por lo tanto no sirve mas....